# How can i install two different laravel project for two different domain in one droplet via command line in digitalocean?

Tags: laravel, server, laravel-5, digital-ocean, vps

I have one droplet in digital ocean and i want to run two or more web application in a single droplet. Kindly guide me how can i install two different laravel project for two different domain   via command line in Digital ocean? Kindly send me the command and how can i forward the domain to that particular web application

Comment: Are the domains correctly pointed to the droplet ?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04